# Selenium: How to drag and drop in Chrome using C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, svg, selenium-chromedriver

The below code works in Firefox but not in Chrome. From what I could find online it seems that Actions.DragAndDrop does not work with Chrome. I am trying to move SVG elements.

Is there an alternative?

```
  var action = new Actions(driver);
  action
    .DragAndDropToOffset(middle, 100, 100)
    .Build()
    .Perform();
```

Selenium.Webdriver: v3.141.0

Selenium.Webdriver.ChromeDriver: v76.0.3809.68

Selenium.Firefox.Webdriver: v0.24.0

Chrome: Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use in Chrome. Remember when using drag and drop you need a starting element to click, and a second element where you are going to drop it.

Call:

```
    var ele1 = Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//button[@class='cz2__images__image-content cz2__images--draggable']"));
    var ele2 = Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//button[@class='Destination']"));

    DragAndDrop(ele1, ele2);
```

Method:

```
    public static void DragAndDrop(IWebElement element1, IWebElement element2)
    {
        WaitForElementEnabled(element1);
        WaitForElementEnabled(element2);
        var builder = new Actions(Driver);
        var dragAndDrop = builder.ClickAndHold(element1).MoveToElement(element2).Release(element1).Build();
        dragAndDrop.Perform();
    }
```

or....

```
    public static void test ()
    {
        var test1 = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("myid"));
        var test2 = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("myid2"));

        Actions builder1 = new Actions(_webDriver);
        IAction dragAndDrop1 = builder1.ClickAndHold(test1).MoveToElement(test2).Release(test1).Build();
        dragAndDrop1.Perform();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me both in Chrome and Firefox :(. One thing i need to mention is that i am trying to move SVG elements. Maybe it matters.

Comment: as long as you can identify the svg elements, this should work. I also added another way to call it above.

Comment: It works if you change the `.Release(element2)` to `.Release(element1)` because you hold the first element not the secound.

Comment: Odd I have used this code for years with no issues lol but I agree it should be element1. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void DragAndDropItem(IWebElement from, IWebElement to)
 {
     Actions action = new Actions(_driver);
     action.DragAndDrop(from, to).Build().Perform();
 }
```