# how to built function for DragAndDrop in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need a common function for DragAndDrop in selenium c#
in which I can pass element1 and element2 to use for drag and drop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium: How to drag and drop in Chrome using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421507/selenium-how-to-drag-and-drop-in-chrome-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions.htm

have you refered the DragandDrop method from the Actions class?

```
 Actions action = new Actions(_driver);
 action.DragAndDrop(from, to).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421507/selenium-how-to-drag-and-drop-in-chrome-using-c-sharp/57422349#57422349